# Multiple Transforms on mousemove jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rotation, transform, mousemove

Probably an easy fix, but for the life of me I can't figure it out or may be overthinking it. In short I have a div that rotatesY based on mousemove. I have that working, but I also need it to translate across the X axis as well. So I know I have to use transform: translateX(value), but not sure how to apply two transforms the best way in jquery. Thanks for the help. Fiddle link below.

Also is there a way to change the rotationY directions?

```js
var $window = $(window),
    $box = $('#box')
    rotation = 0;

$window.on('mousemove', function(event){    
    rotation = (event.pageX/$window.width()*90) - 45;
    $box.css('transform', 'perspective( 600px ) rotateY(' + rotation + 'deg)');
});
```

```css
#box{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 30px auto;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6gbhfxrx/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just apply it at the same time:

```
var $window = $(window),
    $box = $('#box');

$window.on('mousemove', function(event){    
    var rotation = (event.pageX/$window.width()*90) - 45;
    var transX= (event.pageX/$window.width()*500) - 250;
    $box.css('transform', 'perspective( 600px ) rotateY(' + rotation + 'deg) translateX(' + transX + 'px)');
});
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6gbhfxrx/2/

Comment: I see that you have transX in the code what would I want to set that variable to? Possible to show this in a fiddle? Thank you for the reply. EDIT: Tried putting that code in my fiddle and nothing would work, which I am assuming is because transX has no value?

Comment: There you go.  Just keep in mind that when you change the rotation, you're also changing the axis, so 500px isn't quite 500 px across the screen.  If you want to actually move a set amount across the screen, you'll have to do some algebra to figure out the exact amount to move it in both the X and Y direction.

Comment: There is no set amount, I will probably toy with the values to tone down the extremeness of the translate. Again thank you so much!