# CSS And HTML : Apple Phone Like 3D Floating Effect For Images

Tags: javascript, html, css

Actually I don't know how I should call It, but I have Seen that -*(Actually I don't have A IPhone But I have Seen Right!)* In some Apple Phones(Some Or All?)  have a System Like When We rotate the phone The Display Icons And Other staff are like to be floating Moving Slightly Here And There.

It's Cool For Me if I can use it in my website. I need to know How Can I make Such A HTML `img` Using `CSS,HTML` and with or without `JAVASCRIPT` or `JQUERY`. But Instead of Rotating A Phone(Of course no Phone) I need It to be done with the Mouse Pointer. Sample Code or Link for a Code Will Be Useful.

If there Is Already A answered Question Like this, Please Mark this as duplicate (with pleasure) :)

Comment: this is not a question you should ask on stackoverflow, we dont have any clue about your problem

Comment: @ReynaldHenryleo But why? Isn't that information enough?

Comment: at least show us some screen shot and code you have tried before

Comment: well....I'm not such a good CSS coder AT ALL...And that's why I asked From StackOverflow....

Comment: Hi @TheBangBandit. This question is bad because it is more like ramblings of an eccentric. In order for people to help you, write a clear and concise question with examples of what you have tried so far and where it is failing. People are often reluctant to do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you gotta go with Progressive Web App which will allow you to use native features - in this case getting movement of user's phone. This way you'll be able to apply 3D Transforms to DOM elements based on device movement/rotation.

If you want to stick with a cursor as an animation input, there are plenty of libraries and ready examples showing exactly how to do it.

Also, it's already been very well known topic on StackOverflow so you just gotta search a little to find your perfect solution.
StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35016817/8923822
CodePen by Thomas Podgrodzki: https://codepen.io/Podgro/pen/WQpEwY/

```
!(function ($doc, $win) {
var screenWidth = $win.screen.width / 2,
    screenHeight = $win.screen.height / 2,
    $elems = $doc.getElementsByClassName("elem"),
    validPropertyPrefix = '',
    otherProperty = 'perspective(1000px)',
    elemStyle = $elems[0].style;

if(typeof elemStyle.webkitTransform == 'string') {
    validPropertyPrefix = 'webkitTransform';
} else if (typeof elemStyle.MozTransform == 'string') {
    validPropertyPrefix = 'MozTransform';
}

$doc.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    var centroX = e.clientX - screenWidth,
        centroY = screenHeight - (e.clientY + 13),
        degX = centroX * 0.04,
        degY = centroY * 0.02,
        $elem

    for (var i = 0; i < $elems.length; i++) {
        $elem = $elems[i];
        $elem.style[validPropertyPrefix] = otherProperty + 'rotateY('+ degX +'deg)  rotateX('+ degY +'deg)';
    };
});
})(document, window);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always make use of 3rd party libraries.
[Animate.css](https://daneden.github.io/animate.css/)

For your particular animation I believe Shake would be the appropriate one.
Go to their github page to get more information. I've used this almost in each of my websites to add animations. Hope it helps!